# How to reverse this animation when class removed

Tags: html, css, css-animations

My fade in is working when `.fade` is added, but how can I get it to fade out when class is removed? Note that I need it to contain display: none initially.

```
.modal-backdrop {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    &.in {
      animation: modalBackdropFadeIn 1s ease-out;
      display: block;
    }
  }


@-webkit-keyframes modalBackdropFadeIn {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: @xui-modal-backdrop-opacity;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but a possible alternative. Could you use a transition on the original element? That way the new classes effects would reverse smoothly when it's removed.

Comment: Animations don't automatically produce the reverse effect (unlike transitions). You'd have to code the reverse keyframes manually but even then to get it 100% perfect is a pain. You may want to have a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196848/how-to-play-reverse-keyframe-animation-for-hover-off/35197650#35197650